# Bijection between tensor product of a product of modules and product of tensor products of modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, direct-product

> Let $(E_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$ be a family of right $A$-modules and
>   $F$ a finitely generated free left $A$-module. Then the
>   $\mathbf{Z}$-module mapping $$f:\left(\prod_{\lambda\in
>  L}E_\lambda\right)\otimes_AF\rightarrow\prod_{\lambda\in
>  L}(E_\lambda\otimes_AF)$$ such that $f((x_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in
>  L}\otimes y)=(x_\lambda\otimes y)_{\lambda\in L}$ is bijective.

This map is obviously injective. I am trying to prove surjectivity. I am given the following hint:

> By virtue of the fact that the $\mathbf{Z}$-module mapping
>   $$g:\bigoplus_\lambda E_\lambda\otimes_A\bigoplus_\mu
>  F_\mu\rightarrow\bigoplus_{\lambda,\mu}(E_\lambda\otimes_A F_\mu)$$
>   such that $g((x_\lambda)_\lambda\otimes(y_\mu)_\mu)=(x_\lambda\otimes
>  y_\mu)_{\lambda,\mu}$ is bijective, this result is reduced to the case
>   where $F=A_s$. (Note that the families $(E_\lambda) $ and $(F_\mu)$,
>   here, are arbitrary right $A$-modules and left $A$-modules,
>   respectively.)

**Attempt:**

Let $(b_\mu)_{\mu\in M}$ be a finite basis of $F$. The mapping $g:A_s^{(M)}\rightarrow F,\,\xi\mapsto\sum_\mu\xi_\mu b_\mu$, is the unique $A$-module isomorphism such that $b_\mu=g(e_\mu)$, where $(e_\mu)_\mu$ is the canonical basis of $A_s^{(M)}$.

Furthermore, the mapping $\varphi:\left(\prod_\lambda E_\lambda\right)^{(M)}\rightarrow\left(\prod_\lambda E_\lambda\right)^{(M)}\otimes_AF,\,x\mapsto\sum_\mu x_\mu\otimes b_\mu$ is a $\mathbf{Z}$-module isomorphism.

Also, for each $\lambda\in L$, the mapping $h_\lambda:E_\lambda\otimes_A A\rightarrow E_\lambda$ such that $h_\lambda(x\otimes\alpha)=x\alpha$, for $x\in E_\lambda$ and $\alpha\in A$, is an $A$-module isomorphism. Therefore
$$h:\prod_\lambda(E_\lambda\otimes_A A)\rightarrow(\prod_\lambda E_\lambda),\,z\mapsto(h_\lambda(z_\lambda))_\lambda$$
is an $A$-module isomorphism.

I am not sure how to utilize the hint. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

Merely assuming $F$ is free forces $f$ to be injective. It, then, seems that requiring $F$ to also be finitely generated turns $f$ into a bijection. But why does $F$ being finitely generated imply surjectivity?

Comment: For a left $A$-module $F$, the canonical comparison map is injective, surjective, or bijective for all families of right $A$-modules $(E_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in L}$ if and only if $F$ is Mittag-Leffler, finitely generated, or finitely presented respectively. Also, free modules are Mittag-Leffler.

Comment: Another comment: For finitely presented modules $F$ in general, bijectivity of the canonical comparison map requires the axiom of choice. This is because even for the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where tensoring with an abelian group $A$ just gives $A/2A$, one needs to choose representatives for each coordinate to prove surjectivity, and choose "halves" for each coordinate to prove injectivity (i.e. triviality of the kernel).

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: @alf262 It should be noted that you use $L$ as an indexing set for two different things in your question which may cause confusion.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by definition, $A_s^{(M)}=\prod_{m\in M}A_s$ and because $M$ is finite, $\prod_{m\in M}A_s=\oplus_{m\in M}A_s$. Then by the hint, there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module isomorphism

$$\phi:\left(\prod_{\lambda\in L} E_\lambda\right)\otimes_A \left(\bigoplus_{m\in M}A_s\right)\to\bigoplus_{m\in M}\left(\left(\prod_{\lambda\in L}E_\lambda\right)\otimes_A A_s\right).$$

Combine this with your other observations to reduce the problem to the case of establishing that the map

$$f_0:\left(\prod_{\lambda\in L}E_\lambda\right)\otimes_A A_s\to\prod_{\lambda\in L}\left(E_\lambda\otimes_A A_s\right)$$

is an isomorphism.